# Returning struct array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am trying to return a array of structs in my class but I keep getting an error

```
error C2556: 'cellValue *LCS::LcsLength(std::string,std::string)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'cellValue LCS::LcsLength(std::string,std::string)'
```

when I return in my .cpp file

**My class declaration is:**

```
enum arrow {UP, LEFT, DIAGONAL};

struct cellValue
{
    int stringLenght;
    arrow direction;
};

class LCS
{
public:
    cellValue LcsLength (string, string);
};
```

**And when I try returning in my function I have:**

```
cellValue LCS::LcsLength (string X, string Y)
{
    cellValue table[1024][1024];

    return table;
}
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect but even if it were correct your array would be destroyed when the function ends

Comment: According to the the error message, your actual code contains both `cellValue * LcsLength(std::string,std::string)` and `cellValue LcsLength(std::string,std::string)`. The code you posted will have different errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two main issues with your `LcsLength` function: your return type is wrong and you have a dangling pointer.

You declare `LcsLength` as returning a `cellValue` object, but then try and return a `cellValue[1024][1024]`. This is why you are getting your compiler error.

Regardless of the return type, what you are doing will not work, as `table` will be destroyed as soon as the function exits. You would be much better off using `std::vector`, or maybe `std::map` depending on what that table is for.

Answer (score 2):

```
cellValue LCS::LcsLength (string X, string Y)
{
    cellValue table[1024][1024];

    return table;
}
```

The problem here is in understanding that the local array `table` would decay into `cellValue(*)[1024]` and not `cellValue` which is what the function's return type is, as per the definition.

Another issue is, even if you fix the type issue, you'd be returning a local variable's pointer, which would be destroyed when the function goes out of scope and the callee would end up with a dangling pointer i.e. pointer to a loction no longer under your control.

You should go with `std::array` if you must return a collection of objects whose size required is known at compile-time, else go with Tartan's suggestion of using `std::vector`. You wouldn't be incurring any hit in performance too with C++11's guarentees.